# Weird things to do to an image

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, pygame

Here is a program I wrote to take an image and do weird things to it. Is there any more weird things I can add?

Right now I have:

1. Chop the image
2. Flip the image (up/down and left/right)
3. Rotate the image by a random amount of degrees
4. Roll the image by a random offset
5. Negate the image
6. Add a randomly colored border around the image
7. Add a random line to the image
8. Copy a part of the image to another part
9. Negate the red values of the image
10. Negate the green values of the image
11. Negate the blue values of the image

```
import pygame
import random
import subprocess
import sys

inputfilename = sys.argv[1]
outputfilename = "weird.png"

def chop(i: pygame.Surface):
    r = i.get_rect()
    return pygame.transform.chop(i, pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, r.right // 2), random.randint(0, r.bottom // 2), random.randint(0, r.right // 2), random.randint(0, r.bottom // 2)))

def flip(i: pygame.Surface):
    return pygame.transform.flip(i, True, True)

def rotate(i: pygame.Surface):
    b = i.copy()
    b.set_at((0, 0), (0, 0, 0))
    r = pygame.transform.rotate(b, random.randint(0, 360))
    b = pygame.Surface(r.get_size())
    b.fill((0, 0, 0))
    b.blit(r, (0, 0))
    return b

def roll(i: pygame.Surface):
    r = pygame.Surface(i.get_size())
    offset = (random.randint(0, i.get_width() // 2), random.randint(0, i.get_height() // 2))
    r.blit(i, offset)
    r.blit(i, (offset[0] - i.get_width(), offset[1]))
    r.blit(i, (offset[0], offset[1] - i.get_height()))
    r.blit(i, (offset[0] - i.get_width(), offset[1] - i.get_height()))
    return r.copy()

def negate(i: pygame.Surface):
    r = pygame.Surface(i.get_size())
    r.fill((255, 255, 255))
    r.blit(i, (0, 0), special_flags=pygame.BLEND_SUB)
    return r

def addborder(i: pygame.Surface):
    s = random.randint(2, 20)
    r = pygame.Surface((i.get_width() + s + s, i.get_height() + s + s))
    r.fill((random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255)))
    r.blit(i, (s, s))
    return r

def addline(i: pygame.Surface):
    r = i.copy()
    frompos = (random.randint(0, r.get_width()), random.randint(0, r.get_height()))
    topos = (random.randint(0, r.get_width()), random.randint(0, r.get_height()))
    pygame.draw.line(r, (random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255)), frompos, topos, random.randint(1, 20))
    return r

def addcopy(i: pygame.Surface):
    r = i.copy()
    cropped = pygame.Surface((random.randint(0, r.get_width() // 2), random.randint(0, r.get_height() // 2)))
    cropped.blit(r, (random.randint(0, r.get_width() // 2), random.randint(0, r.get_height() // 2)))
    r.blit(cropped, (random.randint(0, r.get_width() // 2), random.randint(0, r.get_height() // 2)))
    return r

def negate_red(i: pygame.Surface):
    r = i.copy()
    for x in range(r.get_width()):
        for y in range(r.get_height()):
            this = r.get_at((x, y))
            r.set_at((x, y), (255 - this[0], this[1], this[2]))
    return r

def negate_green(i: pygame.Surface):
    r = i.copy()
    for x in range(r.get_width()):
        for y in range(r.get_height()):
            this = r.get_at((x, y))
            r.set_at((x, y), (this[0], 255 - this[1], this[2]))
    return r

def negate_blue(i: pygame.Surface):
    r = i.copy()
    for x in range(r.get_width()):
        for y in range(r.get_height()):
            this = r.get_at((x, y))
            r.set_at((x, y), (this[0], this[1], 255 - this[2]))
    return r

print()
img = pygame.image.load(inputfilename)
after = img.copy()
transforms = [chop, flip, rotate, roll, negate, addborder, addline, addcopy, negate_red, negate_green, negate_blue]
for f in range(len(transforms)):
    after = random.choice(transforms)(after)
    # Progress bar
    print(u"\u001b[1A\r\u001b[0K" + str(f + 1) + "/" + str(len(transforms)))

pygame.image.save(after, outputfilename)
subprocess.run(["xdg-open", outputfilename])
```

Comment: Weird indeed. This code, 11 times, selects randomly from 11 transforms; but this is _not_ a random permutation of all 11 transforms. Is this what you intended?

Comment: @Reinderien Yes, this is what I intended. That way, it might do an action twice in a row.

Comment: None of those transformations are weird, they’re some of the basic building blocks of my professional toolbox. The weird thing is to do then in a random order without a specific goal. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should bypass pygame and go straight to Pillow which is more narrowly targeted at image manipulation.

It's good that you have type hints, but your functions are all missing a `->`  return hint.

You can factor out a common function from your `negate_` methods that accepts a channel index between 0 and 2. The Pillow version will not need a double-loop (or indeed any loops at all), and should be able to do a vectorised subtraction using a Numpy array.

Everything from `print()` onward should be moved to a `main()` method, in turn called from an `if __name__ == '__main__'` guard.

[startfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.startfile) tragically has not been made portable, but neither is `xdg-open`. For this application to be portable it needs to switch between the two based on OS.

When you call `subprocess`, strongly prefer `shell=False`; this will require using the absolute path of `/usr/bin/xdg-open`.

`transforms` should be a tuple `()` and not a list `[]`.

Rather than a fixed output filename of `weird.png`, consider adding that as a suffix on the original filename.